# Custom format sum

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding summing two cells in excel.

The content is actually distance from start and the values are written in the following format X + XXX (e.g. 10 +254 km). To this value I have to add another, which has the same format.

Unfortunately I cannot make excel work.

Answer (score 2):

With a sample data:

[image]

You can extract the first part of `B1` with:

```
LEFT(B1,FIND("+",B1)-1)
```

And the second part with:

```
SUBSTITUTE(MID(B1,FIND("+",B1)+1,100),"km","")
```

To get a result in B4 you should concatenate the result of sums of both parts (casted to nummeric format with `--`) using:

```
=SUM(--LEFT(B1:B3,FIND("+",B1:B3)-1)) & " + " & 
 SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(MID(B1:B3,FIND("+",B1:B3)+1,100),"km","")) & " km"
```

This is an array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`)